# How to extract part of string between a specific set of qoutes with stringr?

Tags: r, stringr

I need to extract a specific part of a string that is in between a set of qoutes, and I need to do it without getting subsequent parts of the string that is also inbetween qoutes.

For example if I want to extract only the values between the qoutes after the viewBox attribute in this markup tag;

```
"<svg height=\"512pt\" viewBox=\"-9 0 512 512\" width=\"512pt\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">"
```

I would like to be able to extract a wide variety of different signs, and because of the I have tryed the [:print:] commant in stringr. But I have not been able to limit the extraction to the desired set of qoutes. Moreover, the viewBox is only an example so no specific solutions in regards to that.

```
string <- "<svg height=\"512pt\" viewBox=\"-9 0 512 512\" width=\"512pt\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">"

string %>% 
  str_extract("(?<= viewBox=\")[:print:]+(?<!\" )")
```

The current result is;

```
"-9 0 512 512\" width=\"512pt\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">"
```

Whereas the desired result is:

```
"-9 0 512 512"
```

Comment: Try `str_extract(string, '(?<=viewBox=")-?[0-9 ]+')#[1] "-9 0 512 512"`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, do you have a solution involving [:print:] as well?

Comment: Why do you need `[:print:]`  Is this about extracting numbers after the `viewBox` or something different

Comment: Issue with `print` is that it also includes the `"` and matches those characters after that

Comment: If the extraction is to match all characters till the next `"`, then `str_extract(string, '(?<=viewBox=")[^"]+')`

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun.

This solution;

str_extract(string, '(?<=viewBox=")[^"]+')

seems to be exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can match for characters that are not a double quote (`"`) after the regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, '(?<=viewBox=")[^"]+')
#[1] "-9 0 512 512"
```